# How to return array of objects from multidimensional object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have object:

```
const salary = {
   netto: {
      min: '700.',
      max: '',
   },
   brutto: {
      min: '',
      max: '',
   },
}
```

I want to iterate through object and return array of objects that would look like `[{name: 'netto_min', value: '700'},...etc]` skipping keys with empty value.

I tried:

```
const result = Object.keys(salary).map(type => 
   Object.keys(salary[type]).map(entry => {
      if(salary[type][entry] !== ''){
         return {name: `${type}_${entry}`, value: parseInt(salary[type][entry]).toString()}
      }
   })
)
```

It got me: `[[{name: 'netto_min', value: '700'}, undefined],[undefined, undefined]]`
How can I get `[{name: 'netto_min', value: '700'}]` instead?

Comment: in the value of value you set the value of min ?

Comment: yes, fixed it. Idea was to iterate through all values and if they are present, return them as a part of array of objects. But second map creates second array, I didn't expect, so not sure how to achieve result I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const salary = {
  netto: {
    min: "700.",
    max: ""
  },
  brutto: {
    min: "",
    max: ""
  }
};
let result = Object.keys(salary).map(k => {
  return Object.keys(salary[k]).map(r => ({
     name: `${k}_${r}`,
     value: parseInt(salary[k][r])
    }))
}).flat().filter( b => !isNaN(b.value))
```

Returns

```
[ { name: 'netto_min', value: 700 } ]
```

I'm assuming that the `700.` was a typo on `700`, easily stripped out

Comment: It wasn't error, it was one of accepted values that needs to go through `parseInt`

Comment: @Alyona, got it, updated

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
const salary = {
  netto: {
    min: '700.',
    max: '',
  },
  brutto: {
    min: '',
    max: '',
  },
}

let result = []

for (type in salary) {
  for (entry in salary[type]) {
    let obj = {}
    let value = salary[type][entry]

    if (value) {
      obj.name = `${type}_${entry}`
      obj.value = parseInt(value).toString()

      result.push(obj)
    }
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the keys, then filter that array by if that key is non-empty. then iterate through, and push it to the array and return it.

```js
const salary = {
  netto: {
    min: '700.',
    max: '',
  },
  brutto: {
    min: '',
    max: '',
  },
};

var non_empty_salaries = Object.keys(salary).map(name => {
  var keys = Object.keys(salary[name]);
  var non_empty = keys.filter(key => salary[name][key] != '');
  var non_emptys = [];
  for (let key of non_empty) {
    non_emptys.push({
      name: `${name}_${key}`,
      value: salary[name][key]
    });
  }
  return non_emptys;
});
console.log(non_empty_salaries);
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you need. Try this way:

```
const result = [];

Object.entries(salary).map(entry => {
    const prefix = entry[0];
    const props = Object.entries(entry[1])
    .filter(prop => !!prop[1])
    .map(prop => ({
        name: `${prefix}_${prop[0]}`,
        value: prop[1],
    }));

    result.push(...props);
});
```